# How to calculate average seek time?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm reading Megatron 747 example from the book, "Database System Complete Book 2nd edition" (Example 13.2 pg.565-566). They give the following information:

- 8 platters = 16 surfaces
- 2^16 = 65536 tracks per surface
- 256 sectors per track
- 4096 bytes per sector

When they are calculating the average seek time, they do the following calculation:

```
1 + (65536/3)/4000 = 6.46 millisecond.
```

I understand that 65536 is the number of tracks as given and 1/3 is for averaging the distance, but I can't figure out why they added 1 and where they get the 4000.

Can anyone please help me out??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to know anything about the topic (in fact, what you seem to know just gets you off track, this is about *seek time* only). Just look for all occurrences of `4000` in the description (there's just one), and a related occurrence of `1 millisecond` in the same paragraph.

Quoting *Database System - The Complete Book (2nd edition)*, emphasis mine:

> To move the head assembly between cylinders takes **one millisecond to start and stop**, plus **one additional millisecond for every 4000 cylinders traveled**. Thus, the heads move one track in 1.00025 milliseconds and move from the innermost to the outermost track, a distance of 65,536 tracks, in about 17.38 milliseconds.

Rephrasing the calculation: It takes 17.38 ms to seek from innermost to outermost cylinder. Removing the 1 ms for start/stop leaves 16.38 ms for actual movement. One third of that (moving the average distance according to the author) is 5.46. Add the 1 ms for start/stop back in, you have your answer.

Comment: Oh my, it's not rocket science at all! Thanks for highlighting the lines and your further clarifications!! I was reading the section for hours and just didn't get it. Thanks again!